# Fetch card details from realex

Tags: php, realex-payments-api

I am working on project which uses realex payment gateway. I am just storing payerRef and cardRef at the time of payment. Now I want to get card detail like card number(last four digits), expiry date and card type.I am using realAuth remote method to made transaction.
Is there anyway to get these details?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the API to retrieve this information is only available internally at the moment. We are going to open this API up to developers, but I don't have a firm timeline for you.

You should get the information you need at the time of the payment, so you could store it then as a workaround.

Comment: At the time of development such data were not stored. And now I want to fetch data based on payerRef and cardRef.

Comment: Is this due to be released as an option in the API any time soon?